# How to create database in Google BigTable

Tags: google-app-engine

I know how to create a table in Google Big Table.  But with my constraints I want to create database and store all the tables inside that database.

Comment: What sort of constraints are you talking about?  The GAE DataStore supports references but doesn't enforce them.

Comment: Bigtable is the database/datastore? Can you not just use the it?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the Getting Started documentation for [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) or [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/). The App Engine environment provides your app with a connection to a single datastore instance - you can't create new datastores for your app, so you'll need to partition your data yourself, inside the datastore.

The datastore also doesn't use 'tables' as you may be used to with a relational database, but instead uses 'entity types' to break data up similarly to tables. The documentation has more information on how it all works.